# About sql subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

What to do when we want to select salary of a employee greater than many (lets say 12) employees's salary from a table. I know that we'll have to use a subquery but writing it as :-

```
Select ename,salary 
from emp 
where salary>( select salary
            from emp
           where ename='A'||ename='B'.....)
```

it could be written like that but its not a good approach. Please suggest some useful query for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the 12 employees, I think you want to write the query as:

```
Select ename,salary 
from emp 
where salary> (select max(salary)
               from emp
               where ename in ('A', 'B', . . . )
              )
```

`IN` is much more convenient than a bunch of `or` statements.  And, the subquery needs to return one value, the maximum salary.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select ename,salary 
from emp 
where salary > (
    select salary 
    from 
        (
        select 
           salary, 
           rownum as rn
        from emp
        order by salary
        )
    where rn = 12
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact code that you may use, but it should help you.

You can use RANK() function.

Example from [article at oracle-base.com](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rank-dense-rank-first-last-analytic-functions.php#rank):

```
SELECT empno,
       deptno,
       sal,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY sal) "rank"
FROM   emp;

     EMPNO     DEPTNO        SAL       rank
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7934         10       1300          1
      7782         10       2450          2
      7839         10       5000          3
      7369         20        800          1
      7876         20       1100          2
      7566         20       2975          3
      7788         20       3000          4
      7902         20       3000          4
      7900         30        950          1
      7654         30       1250          2
      7521         30       1250          2
      7844         30       1500          4
      7499         30       1600          5
      7698         30       2850          6
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but its more like finding out grades of employees. In my case i only have to select those employees having salary greater than some specific number of employees.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two different interpretations of your requirement.

*1. What employees earn more than 12 other (random) employees*

and

*2. What employees earn more than 12 specific employees*

This query solves the first requirement, although it will become slow as hell on larger datasets.

```
select *
  from emp a
 where 12 = (select count(*) 
               from emp b 
              where b.salary < a.salary);
```

This query solves the second requirement

```
select * 
  from emp
 where salary > all(select salary 
                      from emp 
                     where emp_id in(1,2,3,4,5)
                   )
```

Comment: For the second query, I think you'd need clarification on required behaviour should any of the listed employees have a null salary.

Comment: Hmm, I think I just found a bug in the optimizer when experimenting with this :)

Comment: As i already told that 'salary greater than some specific employees' so it matches with your second point. Thanks for helping.